# Linux. Why does my Linux command work on the terminal but it doesn't work in a script

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -fu Jor970 --rows $(($(tput lines) --cols $(tput cols) --headers | less
```

Comment: Could it be that non-interactive scripts, depending on how you run them, aren't necessarily connected to a terminal and therefore can't use `tput lines` and `tput cols`. What's the error you're getting? How do you run the script?

Comment: Please share you script so we can debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your command has a typo.

It should be `ps -fu root --rows $(tput lines) --cols $(tput cols) --headers | less`

you have an extra `$(` in from `$(tput lines)` variable.

Comment: thank you mate, I'm new to Linux and appriate the help

Comment: Please keep in mind that in my example I was using the user `root`. You should change to the user you like.